# Select Into doesn't work Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have this two select, the first one worked perfectly. 
But the second, after ran, does not create the table, but the database has grown.
So my database grew but I have no table. Where is my table? And why database grew?
Why the first select worked and the second not? Because have fewer rows?

(Original table cp with 100 million rows)

```
  (1)
  SELECT * INTO r.cp FROM (SELECT id, mol_from_smiles(canonical_smiles::cstring) m 
  FROM cmps LIMIT 1000) tmp WHERE m IS NOT NULL;
  (2)
  SELECT * INTO r2.cp FROM (SELECT id, mol_from_smiles(canonical_smiles::cstring) m 
  FROM cmps) tmp WHERE m IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: what message did you get when executing the second query? did you try `select * from r2.cp` ?

Comment: please update your post to be "ask question", not "ask questions"

Comment: i just got this from the second query: real    920m54.917s
user    0m0.152s
sys     0m0.344s  after the 'select  * from r2.cp' i got this ERROR:  relation "r2.cp" does not exist

Comment: the whole post is 4 questions - please rethink them to be one answerable.